# How do you rename a tag globally in the Craft Control Panel?

Tags: tags, control-panel

Is there a way to rename a tag, globally, within the Craft CP?

If not directly, would the Find and Replace tool include tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Craft 2.0 you can rename tags by double-clicking on them.

[image: Tag editor modal]

Answer (score 3):

A section to manage existing tags (renaming, editing, adding, deleting) [is on the list](https://plus.google.com/112408693722116868145/posts/VZvEvxBrn8X).

Unfortunately you can't use the 'Find and Replace'-tool:

> Added a new Find and Replace tool in Settings, for finding/replacing
>   text within all Rich/Plain Text fields (including ones in a Matrix
>   field).

[See the Changelog of 2.0.2524](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2524)

<s>Currently you can only solve this with a custom plugin or by editing tags directly in the database</s>

**Edit:** See Brandon's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the "Find and Replace" tool, Victor! Always wondered what it does..